# Django: How to edit a gallery that is attached to a project model?

Tags: django, forms, gallery, relation

I have a 'project' model. Each project has a 'gallery' and each gallery has 'photos'.

```
class Project:
 gallery = ForeignKey(Gallery)

class Gallery:
 photos = ManyToManyField(Photo)

class Photo:
 image = ImageField(...)
```

I want to let my users edit the gallery and the project on the same page. Could you tell me what components I need to make this happen? Like which type of form I should use and what technique to use when I process the form with the uploaded images and all?

What to take into account is that I want to show the photos the user is editing with the html img-tag as well as file-tag to let him replace the photo. I don't want django's default m2m-widget which is just a multiselect-list.

Could you help me figure this out, because I simply can't. Been stuck here for three days :)

Comment: Your question is too broad and vague. Are you attempting to modify the built-in Django admin interface, or are you creating a new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't want to use the built in admin module. But I used the formset factory by django. It will let me provide a queryset to the formset (i.e the photos in the gallery). Then I had to provide a small customized model formset class, and then i the view I pretty much had to process the form manually in order to link it correct to the gallery and such..

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your Gallery Admin form using Project as a admin.TabularInline.

Like this:

> admin.py

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from models import Project, Gallery, Photo
from django.contrib import admin

class ProjectInline(admin.TabularInline)
    model = Project

class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ProjectInline]

admin.site.register(Gallery, GalleryAdmin)
```

Comment: But do I have to use the admin app? How can I do without the admin app?